# Slick2D - How to use Fonts

Tags: java, fonts, slick2d

I am coding a game in fonts and I encountered a problem.
I have no idea how to use fonts even though I tried everything.
Can you also please explain what is a glyph?
And where to get .fnt files if that is needed?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157346/slick2d-fonts-dont-work) for an answer about the active AngelCodeFont class

Answer (score 3):

A lot of that stuff is either no longer used, or just not necessary anymore. Basically all you need is a [Graphics](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Graphics.html) instance, and to use something like the [drawString](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float%29) method. You can also use [setFont](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Graphics.html#setFont%28org.newdawn.slick.Font%29) on the [Graphics](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Graphics.html) object to set the font you want to use for rendering.

You can get a [Graphics](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Graphics.html) instance from your [GameContainer](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/GameContainer.html), and then just render to it. If you want to see an example, the `render` method of [this file](https://github.com/normalocity/pedestrians/blob/master/src/com/jefflunt/pedestrians/PedestrianSim.java) in my project on github has some lines in it that render debug information to the screen (fps, memory usage, etc.). The relevant part of the code is:

```
if (ConfigValues.renderSystemInfo) {
  g.setColor(new Color(50, 50, 50, 180));
  g.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 70);
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.drawString("MEM total(used):   " + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1000000) + "(" + ((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/1000000) + ") MB", 10, 25);
  g.drawString("Ped. history size: " + (peds.size()*peds.get(0).getMovementHistory().size()) + " nodes", 10, 40);
}
```

Just for reference, a glyph, at least conceptually, is just the visual representation of a character in a font. So, the way that the letter `a` looks in a given font, for example, is that font's *glyph* for that letter. There's a different glyph for upper and lowercase (`a` or `A`), which is what makes the upper and lowercase letters appear different in fonts.

Answer (score 2):

```
Font font = new Font('Verdana', Font.BOLD, 32);
TrueTypeFont ttf = new TrueTypeFont(font, true);
```

In your update method:

```
ttf.drawString(32.0f, 32.0f, "Your words here", Color.green);
```